# SQL WHERE clause searching for multiple parameters from one field

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause

Essentially I would like the MS Access query to output all records that meet all three of the following criteria:

1. Expanded_Status = "Eligible but not enrolled"
2. Hospital = "UHN"
3. Comments = "transplant" or "tx" or "post-transplant"

The comments field has 3 different versions of the word "transplant" so some fields may have "tx" instead of "transplant" and some records may have "post-transplant" instead of "transplant".

The query below is outputting records that don't match all three of the criteria for some reason.

Please help me modify the query so that I can find only records with all three criteria fulfilled

```
SELECT [First Name], [Last Name], [Subject ID], Expanded_Status, Hospital, Comments
FROM [Barriers UHN Screen - 2017 Mailing]
WHERE Expanded_Status = "Eligible but not enrolled" AND Hospital = "UHN"  AND Comments LIKE "transplant"  OR Comments OR "post transplant" OR Comments = "tx";
```

Comment: The "comments" field has sentences in it so I am looking for the word "transplant" or "tx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zuva,
Try this

```
SELECT 
    [First Name], [Last Name], [Subject ID], Expanded_Status, Hospital, Comments
FROM 
    [Barriers UHN Screen - 2017 Mailing]
WHERE 
    Expanded_Status = "Eligible but not enrolled" AND Hospital = "UHN"  AND 
(Comments = "transplant"  OR Comments = "post transplant" OR Comments = "tx");
```

Enclosing the Comment section of the where clause in brackets, tells access to evaluate each separately as part of the AND clause.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Harun24HR 's answer:

```
SELECT 
    [First Name], [Last Name], [Subject ID], Expanded_Status, Hospital, Comments
FROM 
    [Barriers UHN Screen - 2017 Mailing]
WHERE 
    Expanded_Status = "Eligible but not enrolled" AND Hospital = "UHN"  AND 
(LOWER(Comments) LIKE "*transplant*"  OR LOWER(Comments) LIKE "*post transplant*" OR LOWER(Comments) LIKE "*tx*");
```

I added two things:

1. Calling lower on `Comments` makes sure you are only comparing lower cased string - if someone has "Post Transplant" in the comments, it might not match on "post transplant"
2. Wildcards `*` on the beginning and end of the comparison string - this tells Access my comparison string can be anywhere in the comments.

[Like Operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931)

Comment: I see, thank you. But I want both lower and upper so would it not be best just to omit the lower and keep it as is?

Comment: Because both the left side and the right side are lower case (after called LOWER on Comments), it should match no matter what the casing of the target phrase is in the comments.  You are "normalizing" all of the text to be lower case to make the number of strings you have to compare to make a match as small as possible.